# How are properties of components accessed in componentkit?

Tags: objective-c++, componentskit

in compenentskit if you add a uiswitch as a view how do you access its state? or if you add a textfield how do you access it text?  I have tried setting a property and that has not worked. since the components are separated and specific to their child location there is nothing connecting them.

Answer (score 0):

The file CKComponentDelegateAttribute should be able to allow you to do this.